# Kafka Stream application throwing serialization exception while making foreign key join

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to use new feature *[KTable-KTable Foreign-Key joins](https://kafka.apache.org/25/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#streams-developer-guide-dsl-joins-ktable-ktable-fk-join)* given in `2.5.0`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-stream-processing-application-2");
     props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
     props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
     props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, new JSONSerdeComp<>().getClass());
     props.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "C:\\temp");
     props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

     StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
     KTable<String, OrderObject> ordersTable = builder.<String, OrderObject>table(TOPIC_Agora);
     KTable<String, StockMarketData> stockTable = builder.<String, StockMarketData>table(TOPIC_Stock_Data);

     KTable<String, EnrichedOrder> enriched = ordersTable.leftJoin(stockTable, OrderObject:: getSymbol, new ValueJoiner<OrderObject, StockMarketData, EnrichedOrder>() {

            @Override
            public EnrichedOrder apply(OrderObject order, StockMarketData stock) {
                EnrichedOrder enOrder = EnrichedOrder.builder()
                        .orderId(order.getOrderId())
                        .execPrice(order.getPrice())
                        .symbol(order.getSymbol())
                        .quanity(order.getQuanity())
                        .side(order.getSide())
                        .filledQty(order.getFilledQty())
                        .leaveQty(order.getLeaveQty())
                        .index(order.getIndex())
                        .vWaprelative(order.getVWaprelative())
                        .stockAsk(stock!=null?stock.getAsk().doubleValue():0.0)
                        .stockBid(stock!=null?stock.getBid().doubleValue():0.0)
                        .stockLast(stock!=null?stock.getLast().doubleValue():0.0)
                        .stockClose(stock!=null?stock.getClose().doubleValue():0.0)
                        .build();
                return enOrder;
            }
        } , Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), new JSONSerdeComp<>()));

     enriched.toStream().foreach(new ForeachAction<String, EnrichedOrder>() {
         @Override
        public void apply(String arg0, EnrichedOrder arg1) {

             logger.info(String.format("key = %s, value = %s", arg0, arg1));
        }
    });

     KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
     streams.start();

     Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> streams.close()));
}
```

**Pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Exception:** While running above application I am getting following `Exception`.

```
                18:49:31.525 [my-stream-processing-application-2-37cfd34a-6eb4-411a-a2dc-faa9194ce04e-StreamThread-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager - stream-thread [my-stream-processing-application-2-37cfd34a-6eb4-411a-a2dc-faa9194ce04e-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Failed to flush state store orders-STATE-STORE-0000000000: 
    org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: ClassCastException while producing data to a sink topic. A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.foreignkeyjoin.SubscriptionWrapperSerde$SubscriptionWrapperSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.foreignkeyjoin.SubscriptionWrapper). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters (for example if using the DSL, `#to(String topic, Produced<K, V> produced)` with `Produced.keySerde(WindowedSerdes.timeWindowedSerdeFrom(String.class))`).
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:94) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.foreignkeyjoin.ForeignJoinSubscriptionSendProcessorSupplier$UnbindChangeProcessor.process(ForeignJoinSubscriptionSendProcessorSupplier.java:157) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.foreignkeyjoin.ForeignJoinSubscriptionSendProcessorSupplier$UnbindChangeProcessor.process(ForeignJoinSubscriptionSendProcessorSupplier.java:71) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.TimestampedCacheFlushListener.apply(TimestampedCacheFlushListener.java:45) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.TimestampedCacheFlushListener.apply(TimestampedCacheFlushListener.java:28) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.lambda$setFlushListener$1(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:119) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.putAndMaybeForward(CachingKeyValueStore.java:92) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.lambda$initInternal$0(CachingKeyValueStore.java:72) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:151) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:109) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.flush(ThreadCache.java:124) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.flush(CachingKeyValueStore.java:272) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.flush(WrappedStateStore.java:84) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.lambda$flush$7(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:192) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.flush(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:192) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:282) [kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.flushState(AbstractTask.java:177) [kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.flushState(StreamTask.java:554) [kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:490) [kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:478) [kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.commit(AssignedTasks.java:226) [kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.commitAll(TaskManager.java:543) [kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:977) [kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:823) [kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697) [kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670) [kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.messages.JSONSerdeCompatible
        at com.messages.JSONSerdeComp.serialize(JSONSerdeComp.java:1) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.foreignkeyjoin.SubscriptionWrapperSerde$SubscriptionWrapperSerializer.serialize(SubscriptionWrapperSerde.java:79) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.foreignkeyjoin.SubscriptionWrapperSerde$SubscriptionWrapperSerializer.serialize(SubscriptionWrapperSerde.java:51) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:176) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:111) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:89) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.0.jar:?]
        ... 34 more
```

Any idea why I am getting following error even though I have used `default serialization config`.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me on a first glimpse. Can you file a ticket?

Comment: Thanks for the ticket. Linking it here to close the loop: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10049